# Drawing UI components when device orientation changes

Tags: iphone

When I open any form in my app in Portrait mode and tap on any textfield (keyboard pops up) and then change the device orientation to landscape, page is no longer scrollable to bottom most UI widgets. But if you open the same page directly in Landscape mode, it works fine

I think idea should be like:
1. Capture the change in device orientation
2. Change the frames of UI components as required
3. Redraw the screen

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You simply set adjust your frame for landscape mode.. U did not allocate memory just adjust frame only...